# Replicating standard D3.js Conical US Albers projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, united-states, d3, albers

Oftentimes, when I see maps of the US rendered online, they use a [custom version](https://observablehq.com/@d3/u-s-map) of the Albers projection, like so:

[image]

Alaska and Hawaii are off to the side, nicely arranged. I'd like to replicate this sort of thing in QGIS.

Would it be possible for me to do this?

Is this a D3-only projection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually three map projections. For example, Hawaii has been magnified and Alaska has been greatly reduced in size.

So you cannot do this in the main map display, but you can produce maps for printout that look this by using the Composer and creating 3 inset maps.

The Composer is essentially a Layout Manager intended to make final images, posters, printouts, etc:

https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/overview_composer.html

Considering the three maps all have different scales, I would recommend you also add scales to the three maps.